# Why we ignored the $e^\infty$ term in the result?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, infinity

In [Question (2.20)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fcEe.jpg) of Griffiths' Quantum Mechanics book, they have given this [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leV5I.jpg).

In the Solution of question 2.20(b), they omitted $e^{(ik-a) \infty}$ (or may have considered $e^{(ik-a) \infty}=0$) in this calculation[image: calculation of 2.20(b)].

How can it be correct at all?

Comment: Is the number $a$ greater than $0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, it is a real positive constant (mentioned in the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{ikx-ax}=0$. And this follows from the fact that$$\left|e^{ikx-ax}\right|=e^{\operatorname{Re}(ikx-ax)}=e^{-ax},$$together with the fact that$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-ax}=0$$
for $a>0$.

Comment: But, $$\begin{aligned} &\left|e^{i k x-a x}\right| \\=& R e\left(e^{-a x}(\cos k x-i \sin k x)\right) \\=& e^{-a x} \cos k x \end{aligned}$$

Comment: The first equality is false.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Even if you were right, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-ax}=0$ and $\cos(kx)$ is bounded, we would still have $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-ax}\cos(kx)=0$.

Comment: You seem to think that $|e^z|=\operatorname{Re}(e^z)$. This is not true.

Comment: then, @José Carlos Santos, what does the | | operator do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135974/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-lusypher).